# Where to store consistent application properties?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, properties

I'm building a Swing application in Java and I want the colours to be consistent. So I could do something like:

```
public class Colours {
    public static final String BACKGROUND = "#D9DADE";
}
```

But then I thought maybe an enum would be better, so I did this:

```
public enum ColourStyles { 
    BACKGROUND("#D9DADE");

    private String colourValue;

    private ColourStyles(String value) {
        colourValue = value;
    }

    public String getColourValue() {
            return colourValue;
    }
};
```

But then that made the String now a ColourStyle type and I can't decode it using `Color.decode(BACKGROUND)`.

Is there any better way of doing this completely, like a properties file? I've done Wicket but never come across the same sort of structure for labels/colours in Swing.

Thanks!

Comment: You can decode it with `Color.decode(BACKGROUND.getColourValue)` or you could store it as an integer instead, or as a Color, within the class. BACKGROUND(new Color(....)) for example.

Comment: using an enum or a constant class is not a bad approach, you can also better use a property file, so you can change without compiling again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 options are good, but i'd prefer a 3rd way and it's using a property file. So you don't have to recompile your application if you want to change.

1st)

```
public final class Colours {

private Colours(){}

public static final BACKGROUND = "#D9DADE";

}
```

.
2nd) It's ok, but you can add a method to the enum to return the color.

```
public enum ColourStyles { 
    BACKGROUND("#D9DADE");

    private String colourValue;

    private ColourStyles(String value) {
        colourValue = value;
    }

    public String getColourValue() {
            return colourValue;
    }

    public Color getColour(){
      return Color.decode(colourValue);
    }

}
```

And 3rd) create a file for example `lookAndFeel.properties`

```
colour.background=#D9DADE
```

Make a class that could be a `singleton` to load the properties file and you can add a util method to return the colour like in the enum, the good thing of this is that you can change the values wihout compiling again your application.

4th) If you are using a customizable look&feel you can set that properties using `UIManager.put();` to set properties for all components. Here is an example of properties for Nimbus L&F [Nimbus defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

Comment: I'm not using a full custom look & feel, I'm getting the system L&F and just changing the background.